# How to use zscore with numba

Tags: python-3.x, loops, numba

I'm trying to make a cross correlation matrix and a shift matrix of 2800x2800, but i want to normalize the value. For that, i'm using zscore, but numba don't recognize it. I got to find something because i can't make a double loop like that without numba. My code look like that:

@njit

```
def crossCor(timeSeries):
for i in range(timeSeries.shape[0]):
    print(i)
    for j in range(timeSeries.shape[0]):
        cor = (np.correlate(zscore(timeSeries, axis = 1)[i, :], zscore(timeSeries, axis = 1)[j, :], mode = 'full')) / timeSeries.shape[1]
        crossCorrelation[i, j] = max(cor[timeSeries.shape[1] - 11:timeSeries.shape[1] - 1])
        crossCorrelation[j, i] = max(cor[timeSeries.shape[1] - 1:timeSeries.shape[1] + 9])
        decalage[i, j] = timeSeries.shape[1] - 1 - np.where(cor == max(cor[timeSeries.shape[1] - 11:timeSeries.shape[1] -1]))[0][0]
        decalage[i, j] = np.where(cor == max(cor[timeSeries.shape[1] - 1:timeSeries.shape[1] + 9]))[0][0] - timeSeries.shape[1] - 1
```

@njit is one line before the def, but stack won't make my code look good if i try to put it in the code section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're referring to the [`zscore` function from Scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.zscore.html), since you didn't specify.

According to the [Numba reference manual](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/index.html), Numba only supports a certain set of Python features and Numpy features out of the box. So you could either find a way to make this function work with Numba or find a Numba-compatible implementation of `zscore` or try to implement your own within the constraints of Numba.

With a quick search I also found a project which aims at "making Numba aware of Scipy", but its documentation seems lacking: https://github.com/numba/numba-scipy

Edit: another option would be to use `zscore` exclusively outside/before using the function you're applying `numba.jit` to, thus avoiding the problem entirely.

Edit 2: for further reference on features supported by Numba

- [List of supported Python features](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/pysupported.html)
- [List of supported Numpy features](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/numpysupported.html)

Comment: I found a solution, I z-score my data out of the loop before. However, now Numba won't let me use np.correlate(mode = 'full').

Comment: @Wil Numba currently [supports](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/numpysupported.html#other-functions) only the first 2 arguments of [`np.correlate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html), not including the "mode" argument.